# Modify table row while export/import table to another database SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I have issue with my production database, so I want to reproduce the issue on my development database. The DBMS I use is SQL Server 2016 (SP1)

To reproduce the error I'm copying all the data to development database using Export in SQL Server Management Studio.

The production database is running and user still using the database, so there's gonna be insert, update, or even delete row **while I'm exporting the data**.

- What will happen to the modified row(insert, update, or even delete) while I'm exporting the data. Will it be exported to my development database? And why, like how SQL Server handle something like this?
- What is the good way to move production database to development database?
- And the extreme one, What will happen if table columns modified while export is in process?

EDIT : 
I need to mention that the DBMS version on production is higher then  development so I can't use backup/restore to move database

Comment: Backup/restore?

Comment: Check [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/). It states that SSIS elements have SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level..

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal already try that, but I have issue because the DBMS version on production database is higher then the development database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the good way to move production database to development
>   database

You should `backup` your database on the production server and `restore` it on the dev server.
This will not block user activity on the prod

> What will happen to the modified row(insert, update, or even delete)
>   while I'm exporting the data.

If your `insert`/`update` is concurrent but the reading process is already strated on a table, your changes will be blocked. Vice versa, if any `DML` is already started on the same rows, reading process will wait until modification is committed/rollbacked.

> And the extreme one, What will happen if table columns modified while
>   export is in process?

While you are reading `Sch-S` lock is held on the table, so no column modification can be done until this lock is released.

Comment: Is there any way to move database beside backup/restore ? because my DBMS version on production is higher then the development

Comment: Other ways are SSIS package (and it's what Import/Export Wizard uses), Copy database wizard (it also creates SSIS package but for all the tables), or scripting your database schema + bcp